# How to refer to self (model) in mongoengine document definition

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'd like to sett `uuid` base on items count in my database.

```
class Order(Document):
    uuid = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.uuid = self.gen_uuid()

    def gen_uuid(self):
        date = datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')
        count = self.objects.count()
        return date + str(count)
```

Unfortunately, referring to `self.objects.count()` throws `AttributeError: 'QuerySetManager' object has no attribute 'count`.

I'm confused because this is the API way of accessing model data. Thus, my question is, what is the correct way of referring to model data in model definition?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Replacing `self` with `model name` fixed my problem.

```
# from 
count = self.objects.count()

# to 
count = Order.objects.count()
```